# Change chart bar offset (OffsetPercent) at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

There is a property inside Teechart edit window named bar offset. Like the following picture. Inside .dfm file it's name is OffsetPercent.

Q: How to change it at runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OffsetPercent` property is published by the `TCustomBarSeries` class, so you can typecast the series which is this series type descendant to access the property, e.g.:

```
TCustomBarSeries(Chart1.Series[0]).OffsetPercent := 65;
```

Or, if you know the exact series type, e.g. in your case the `THorizBarSeries`:

```
THorizBarSeries(Chart1.Series[0]).OffsetPercent := 65;
```

I've intentionally *missed* a class type testing (with the `is` operator) since it's not relevant for the answer, but you should use it in your real code if you weren't sure about the series class type you're accessing.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot.